# Vue.js how to load dependent components

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Vue.js : how to load dependent components?

From router currently using component as follows:

```
import A from './A';

export default {
    components : {
        'new-comp-A' : NewCompA 
    }
}
...
```

But this renders the template before import causing errors. Is there a better way for loading dependencies?

The template uses the  - did you register the component correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What error does it give you? Based upon your code, everything seems normal to me.

Comment: But this renders the template before import causing errors. Is there a better way for loading dependencies?

The template uses the <new-comp-A 
But it was throwing :
[Vue warn]: unknown custom element <new-comp-A> - did you register the component correctly.

Comment: "Did you register the component correctly"?

Comment: It looks like we are going to need to see all of the code you are using to try and import your component. One thing I can think of is the path may be wrong? Also, try to use it like: `<new-comp-a>` versus `<new-comp-A>`, that may also be your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your casing is incorrect. Use either `'NewCompA'` or `'new-comp-a'` for the name.

In fact, it would be even easier to use

```js
import NewCompA from 'wherever/the/component/is/defined'

export default {
  components: {
    NewCompA
  }
}
```

Your template can then use either

```html
<NewCompA></NewCompA>
<!-- or -->
<new-comp-a></new-comp-a>
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Name-Casing

Comment: yes,, that got fixed.. but i got another error..  while registering a component in beforeMount() method  i am using it in template ... but it throws up the error ..    the reason for doing this is because it needs the imports libs on the top..

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your code again, it does not seem normal. You are assigning the variable `A` to your component, but trying to import it with the variable `NewCompA`..

You need to change the following:

***From this:***

```
import A from './A';

export default {
    components : {
        'new-comp-A' : NewCompA 
    }
}
...
```

***To this:***

```
import A from './A';

export default {
    components : {
        'NewCompA' : A
    }
}
...
```

***and use it like this:***

```
<new-comp-a>
```